# Bootstrap3: How to make 2 columns with same height (again)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

before you kill me: I red all the other solutions and non of them worked... or I couldn't make them work. I've been sitting here for hours on this problem and can't solve it (without js).

my problem is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n1yL08q6/3/

I'm using bootstrap 3 and a design for widgets which is included in the fiddle.

Some solutions in so and other places say I need to use table display. I tried this (which didn't work):

```
.row-full-height {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.col-full-height {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: -5000px; padding-bottom: 5000px
}
```

You can also see that I tried to implement the `margin-bottom` trick, which didn't work either.

I also tried to work with flex, which actually works, but it also breaks the width of the column: http://jsfiddle.net/n1yL08q6/2/

it is possible that I didn't implement this solutions very well. Any idea where could be the error?

Comment: I tried this 2 solutions and didn't work... but as I said it is possible that I could't implement them right.

Comment: What is the width of the columns supposed to be?  You can use flex-basis to set the default/base width of the column before it scales.

Comment: The width is governed by bootstrap. I use columns, and the width is suppose to change if the screen size changes.

Comment: You have given the left widget a fixed height of 319px and the other not. Why did you make that different?

Comment: @LoekBergman this isn't important. I was just experimenting around. I don't want to use fixed values. sorry for the misunderstanding.